# Nextjs 13 exportPathMap uses pages dir instead of app dir to generate

Tags: next.js

I want to export my build to a different folder for reasons but it doesn't properly work. I'm using Next.js 13 and use the experimental app directory feature.

This is my `next.config.js` file and it doesn't include an `exportPathMap`.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

```
info  - using build directory: /home/foxy/programming/tauri/tauri-app/.next
info  - Copying "static build" directory
info  - No "exportPathMap" found in "pathToRootOfProject/next.config.js". Generating map from "./pages"
info  - Launching 31 workers
info  - Exporting (2/2)
PageNotFoundError: Cannot find module for page: /
    at Object.getPagePath (pathToRootOfProject/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js:77:15)
    at pathToRootOfProject/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:376:48
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at pathToRootOfProject/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:367:69
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (pathToRootOfProject/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20) {
  code: 'ENOENT'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I already tried to redownload node_modules and that didn't work either.